# My CPU fan is constantly at ~500RPM - LOW SPEED

Tags: cpu, hardware-failure, fan, overheating

I have tried setting the RPM in the bios but the only two settings are "Off" and "Slow". My mobo is DP55WG and it is updated. I am using an 212 EVO heatsink + fan and the fan is plugged in the correct place according to the mobo manual. The fan can do 2000RPM but I can not in any software set its speed successfully.

I get this error with Intel Desktop Utilities - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp6sk.png

Any help would be greatly apreciated

FIXED: I got speedfan and had to set the fan to manual mode in advanced settings. Then change a couple of options so it acts according to the core temperatures. Now it runs up to 1600RPM. I also added a second fan under the heatsink - I control it with Speedfan too

Comment: Are you sure the fan has the proper power cable allowing it to have variable speed?  There are several connectors, one being, a low power low rpm cable.

Comment: FIXED: I got speedfan and had to set the fan to manual mode in advanced settings. Then change a couple of options so it acts according to the core temperatures. Now it runs up to 1600RPM.    
        
I also added a second fan under the heatsink - I control it with Speedfan too